# How can I test code within a textarea through React UI with an onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

So I’m using a code mirror and want to be able to test user input in javascript code upon an onClick event. Similar to a codewars clone. I’m somewhat familiar with mocha.js and am attempting to use it,
but havent figured out how to implement it into react UI